# Пререндеринг первого экрана

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

Планируется переехать на vue js рендеринг и есть опасения, что SEO страницы упадёт. Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы в index.html был уже срендеренный код, практически такой же, как был раньше при php рендере? Я читал про SSR, но это кажется не нужным. Это лишь одна страница, и важен лишь первый экран.

Comment: `SEO страницы упадёт`. Если это про "проиндексирует или нет?", то проиндексирует и Яндекс, и Гугл, проверил на своем сайте. Чем `SSR` не устраивает?

Comment: SSR может рендерит в index.html ?

Comment: Попробовал prerender-spa-plugin не понимаю в чем его смысл работы, он так и оставляет index.html пустой <div id="app"> мне тогда проще просто запихать туда статический html и чтобы он затирался при иницилизации VUE